# Python: strip() method not removing whitespace from text

Tags: python, debugging

I have a problem where what looks like whitespace preceding a string isn't removed using the strip method. This is the script:

```
text = '"X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475";'
startpos = text.find(":")
endpos = text.find('\";', startpos)
extracted_text = text[startpos+1:endpos]
extracted_text.strip()
print("Substring:",extracted_text)
```

This returns:

```
Substring:    0.8475
```

Assuming that strip() was used correctly, any advice on debugging to identify what is actually printed to screen that appears to be whitespace but isn't?

Comment: Its could be a \t

Comment: Just use `print("Substring:",extracted_text.strip())`. As @chepner says -- `strip()` doesn't modify the string but instead creates a new one. In any event -- you should read up on regular expressions. You are doing way too much work for this sort of thing.

Comment: Or write `extracted_test = extracted_text.strip()`

Comment: Sorry, I replaced "score" with "extracted_text" in the print method.

Comment: Thank you -- "values are immutable" -- that was the issue and solution was "extracted_text = extracted_text.strip()". Out of curiosity, is there a debugger that would have flagged this?

Comment: Of course, try VS Code with Pylance for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-assign the variable:

`extracted_text=extracted_text.strip()`

Alternatively:

`print("Substring:",extracted_text.strip())`

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip` does not happen in-place it returns the stripped string.

In order to isolate the last number without the trailing characters you can use a combination of `str.strip` and `str.split` then get the second value and remove the trailing characters using `str.replace`:

```
>>> text.strip().split()[1].replace('";', '')
'0.8475'
```